# Search using multiple criteria in excel

Tags: excel

Here is a quick sheet i made to try and demonstrate what im trying to achieve. I looked an couldnt quite find an answer that fit what im trying to do.

I would like to type in the criteria in to the teal boxes and for it to return the proper price based on the level. So in this instance it should return 3.9

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZAAeoBzgePwW_Ypp5L0Td7JUeRjHfV4J--UFZ1gxV0c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIFS() with INDEX/MATCH to return the correct column:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(F8:J10,,G4),A8:A10,B4,B8:B10,C4,C8:C10,D4,D8:D10,E4,E8:E10,F4)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, I up-vote your answer. Can you please explain how `G4` working as `column_num` here in `Index()` function?